# JenkinsのGerrit Pluginでcommit userのフィルタがしたい

Tags: jenkins

JenkinsのGerrit Pluginにてイベントをトリガする際、
プロジェクトやブランチ、ファイルパスでフィルタする方法はわかるのですが、

他フィールド(例えばcommit userやcommit message)でフィルタすることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

恐らくPluginとしてのフィルタ方法はなく、ジョブ側でフィルタするしかなさそうだという結論になりました。

それだと不要なトリガでもビルドログが増えていってしまうので避けたかったのですが・・・